# How to get the most matched value from a python dictionary

Tags: python, string-matching

I have a dictionary of job category keywords looks like this:

```
{'01': ['advertising, representatives, financial, miscellaneous, other, sales'],
 '02': ['musicians, workers, officials, entertainers, actors, singers, competitors, dancers'],
 '03': ['movers, station, gas, of, stock, pumping, workers, hoist, mining, freight, truck'],
 '04': ['child, support, children, disable, supplemental, security, income']}
```

I also have a list of job titles:

```
child support
art director
driver
assistant specialist
```

I am wondering if there is a way to find the most matched job category for each job title. So what I want is a new column of a key from the dictionary for each in the job title list.

```
job title             category     
child support           04
art director            23
truck driver            03
assistant specialist    17
```

The key is representing a broad job category.
The value in this dictionary is split unique words of more detailed subcategory names. 
A problem is the words in job title may not exist in any category names.
And the words may exist in many categories.

Comment: from the example: why would `child support` by category 81? Wouldn't it be '04'? The category numbers in your second example even don't exist in the dictionary or am I'm wrong?

Comment: @GüntherJena I think the example they are giving us contains a dumbed down data set.

Comment: Why do the categories contain a single list with one item? Instead of `"01":["cat1, cat2, ..."]` Could `"01":["cat1","cat2", ...]` work?

Comment: Take the values in the keyword string and split them by the comma and convert them into a `set`. Then you can take each job description and split it into words and iterate over the sets to see which has the maximum number of matches. It's simplistic but seems appropriate if its something you are coding yourself as a beginner.

Comment: Sorry, you are not wrong. the child support should be '04'. I just want to show the desired final layout. I'll edit a bit

Comment: @MustacheMoses You're right, a list that way makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following solution:

```
def match_job_title(category_dict, job_title):                                                                           
  job_title=set(job_title.split(' ')) # make a set with job title words                                                                                   
  best_match=0 # the best number of  matches                                                                                                          
  best_category=None # the best category                                                                                                    

  for category, keywords in category_dict.items(): # iterate through category dict                                                                      
    keywords=set(keywords[0].split(sep=', ')) # make set of keywords                                                                            
    matches=len(keywords.intersection(job_title)) # intersect and get number of elements                                                                        
    if matches>best_match: # if it's better use this category                                                                                             
      best_match=matches                                                                                                 
      best_category=category                                                                                             

  return best_category
```

Using it via:

```
>>> d={ '01': ['advertising, representatives, financial, miscellaneous, other, sales'],                                      
        '02': ['musicians, workers, officials, entertainers, actors, singers, competitors, dancers'],                          
        '03': ['movers, station, gas, of, stock, pumping, workers, hoist, mining, freight, truck'],                            
        '04': ['child, support, children, disable, supplemental, security, income']}

>>> match_job_title(d, 'child support')
04
>>> match_job_title(d, 'financial femme fatal')
01
>>> match_job_title(d, 'circus clown')==None
True
>>> for job in ['child support', 'art director', 'truck driver']:
...   print(job, match_job_title(d, job))
child support 04
art director None
truck driver 03
```

A more pythonic dictionary would look like this (would need minor adaptions in code above):

- keys seems to be `int`, so let them be `int`
- values should be [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) of keywords

Example:

```
{1: {'advertising', 'representatives', 'financial', 'miscellaneous', 'other', 'sales'},
 2: {'musicians', 'workers', 'officials', 'entertainers', 'actors', 'singers', 'competitors', 'dancers'},
 3: {'movers', 'station', 'gas', 'of', 'stock', 'pumping', 'workers', 'hoist', 'mining', 'freight', 'truck'},
 4: {'child', 'support', 'children', 'disable', 'supplemental', 'security', 'income'}}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have a huge list of job titles so I cannot run this function for each job title?

Comment: Sure, just added an example

Comment: @Vera.J if you think this answer was solving your problem please consider checking this answer as the correct one. thx